# MongoDB: how do I authenticate when executing the `copydb` command

Tags: mongodb, authentication

I have a replica set on a remote host which requires authentication in order to connect. The original (root) user was created in the `admin` database which I have used in order to remotely connect. I building some sort of a "backup" script which copies a db into the replica set and in a later time I should be able to copy a db from the remote location into other MongoDB instances.

So I wrote the script to copy a database by connecting **TO** the remote location, authenticating and then running the `db.runCommand` using `copydb: 1`. It works great, no problems here.

When I try to copy a db back into my local machine that's when things go wrong, mainly because I have to authenticate as part of the `copydb` command. I originally tried to use the same technique (`db.runCommand`) but since the nonce and key authentication are messy by themselves I tried to solve the problem first by writing the commands manually into mongo's shell using `db.copyDatabase`, according to the documentation it should do this process for me.

This is the command:

```
db.copyDatabase('from_db', 'to_db', 'remote.host.example.com', 'my_user', 'my_password')
```

Which responds with:

```
{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "Authentication failed.", "code" : 18 }
```

I tried switching roles (root, userAdmin, readWrite, ...) but nothing works. I tried creating another user inside the db I am trying to copy, but that didn't seems to do much other than change the response a little into:

```
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "unable to login { ok: 0.0, code: 18, errmsg: \"Authentication failed.\" }"
}
```

I searched everywhere, went over anything in the manual which seemed remotely relevant and I still can't figure it out.

How am I suppose to copy a db from a remote location which requires an authentication??

Comment: You tried with : db.auth("superuser", "superuser_password") before execute copy?

Comment: If I run `db.auth` on my local host it's not gonna affect my remote host. They don't share users, so the authentications are different.

Comment: Ok, sorry, the versions of mongdb are the same? What version is?

Comment: I only realized a couple of minutes ago, no. The remote is 3.2.1 and the local is 3.0.6, I'll try to match the two and see if it helps.